# How ever does one log off the Kik app on an S3?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3

I downloaded an app called Kik off the Play store and I can't seem to find a way to log out of it so it doesn't drain my battery since it uses push notifications.  Any tips?  So odd that unless you want to uninstall it you can't seem to turn it off.

OS: 4.1

Answer (score 1):

If it uses push notifications, it doesn't drain your battery. That's the whole point of push: the app doesn't need to be running at all. Instead, the app is started by Android (specifically, by the Google Cloud Messaging service) when a message arrives.

Answer (score 0):

Well, according to KiK officials they don't have logout feature. But you can force a logout by resetting the app but the downside is this is going to wipe your conversation history. So, rest I would leave it to you to decide wether to remain logged in and keep draining the battery or force a logout by resetting the app.